# Merging multiple dataframes together that have different columns except 5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I push 1,424 dataframes into a list as so:

```
import os
df = []
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(output_path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(output_path, filename)))
    else:
        continue
```

I want to merge all of them together. Here is an example I want to emulate using only 2 dfs:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('../output/2009/census_data_2009_p1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('../output/2009/census_data_2009_p2.csv')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on = ['Location+Type', 'Year', 'state', 'Census_tract', 'County_name'])
```

How would I do the latter but for all of them in the df list? Specifically I want to do a left join on all the dataframes using the keys `'Location+Type', 'Year', 'state', 'Census_tract', 'County_name'`

I am currently getting this error even though I have 64 gb of RAM.

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

This occurs when I either run this code:

```
from functools import reduce
df_merged = reduce(lambda l, r: pd.merge(l, r, 
                                         how='left',
                                         on=['Location+Type', 
                                             'Year',
                                             'state',
                                             'Census_tract',
                                             'County_name']), dfs)
```

or this code

```
[
    dfi.set_index(
        ["Location+Type", "Year", "state", "Census_tract", "County_name"], inplace=True
    )
    for dfi in df
]

df[0].join(df[1:], how="left")
```

Comment: Please show us some sample data with expected output and tell us why `pd.concat` as described in the answer below did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive one of the cleanest options is to map the merge operation using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```py
from functools import reduce
df_merged = reduce(lambda l, r: pd.merge(l, r, 
                                         how='left',
                                         on=['Location+Type', 
                                             'Year',
                                             'state',
                                             'Census_tract',
                                             'County_name']), df)
```

This assumes that the dataframes are sorted in the desired way, however.

A more memory efficient way to do this (but arguably less clean) is to simply iterate the dataframes:

```py
df_merged = df[0].copy() # we use the initial dataframe to start
del df[0]
for _ in range(len(df)): 
    df_merged = df_merged.merge(df[0],
                                how='left', 
                                on=['Location+Type', 
                                    'Year',
                                    'state',
                                    'Census_tract',
                                    'County_name'])
    # this will free up the contents of the recently merged dataframe   
    del df[0]
```

Comment: What do you mean by sorted in the desired way?

Comment: Also, SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Also, getting this error: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. I am guessing I may need more RAM even though I have 64gb?

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the syntax error. I also added another option (arguably less pretty) that should take less memory to run. By sorted in the desired way, I mean that the order of left joining will matter (only the rows that match what was already merged will be added to the merge)

Comment: When you say dataframes are sorted in the desired way what do you mean?

Comment: To expand a little bit on the order issue. For isntance, if in the first dataframe you don't have ALL the combination of keys that you include on the `on` parameter, then you might lose some of the rows that come in subsequent datasets. It's in that sense that the order matters.

Comment: Thanks, inside the for loop shouldn't it be df[i] instead of df[0]?

Comment: I've edited my answer. But no, we're deleting the first element (`0`th element) every time, so the `df` list shrinks on every iteration (that's why I do a `for` over a range and not on the list itself)

Comment: I see, so it still goes through each dataframe in the df list?

Comment: Yes, you can test this using a similar for loop on a regular list `a = list(range(10))` and then (in a for loop similar to the one in my answer) do: `print(a[0])
    del a[0]`

Comment: I was able to break it up into 2 csv files each size begin 3.5 gb and 6.5 gb respectively. From there I try to merge those 2 and I get a memory error. Is this normal given that I have 64gb of ram? I feel like there must be something I am doing wrong.

Comment: It does sound rather strange. Could you check the memory usage while running the script? I see how joining will increase the memory usage, but not by that much.

Comment: I just tested this with dummy data (10 dataframes of 1GB each, 5 columns in common + 10 numerical columns with random values and random column names), and it worked just fine on a computer with 16GB of RAM

Comment: That is odd, I tried both on Ubuntu and Windows. On Windows I eventually get a memory error like the one I mentioned in the post and the RAM goes to 100% evenutally. With Ubuntu eventually it just breaks the notebook and says that it will restart automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try using set index and join:

```
[
    dfi.set_index(
        ["Location+Type", "Year", "state", "Census_tract", "County_name"], inplace=True
    )
    for dfi in df
]

df[0].join(df[1:], how="left")
```

Comment: Where is the dfi in the join?

Comment: Also, getting this error: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. I am guessing I may need more RAM even though I have 64gb?

Comment: Looks we are blowing through your memory on your computer.

Comment: try with like 10 dataframes if that works, increase it until you get the error.  Maybe do two smaller joins then join the two parts together.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a little clean up in the first block of code:

```
import os
dfs = []
for filename in os.listdir(output_path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(output_path, filename)))
```

To combine a list of DataFrames into a single DataFrame:

```
pd.concat(dfs, join='inner')
```

The `join='inner'` picks only the common columns among the list of DataFrames.

A short demo:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [2,3,1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [2,3,1]], columns=['b', 'c', 'd'])

    b   c   d
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   1

pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')

    b   c
0   2   3
1   3   1
0   1   2
1   2   3
```

Note the resulting index. If required, you can use `reset_index()` to reset the index.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I would need not just the common columns but all the columns from each dataframe. Hence the performing a left join on the common column names.

Comment: Would joining using 'outer' then dropping duplicates do the trick?

Comment: Just to clarify, you didn't want to concatenate (row-wise) all the DataFrames together?

Comment: No, I want to do a left join on all the dataframes since they all have unique columns except for the 5 I listed above.

Comment: You question is not clear to me. `merge()` could only deal with two DataFrame objects, i.e., left and right. A left join may produce more row than the left table. Can you give some examples of your tables?

Comment: @yoonghm See other answers they seem to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# For the columns in the variable
columns = ['Location+Type', 'Year', 'state', 'Census_tract', 'County_name']

# Set the indexes in order to join by index
for my_df in df:
  my_df.set_index(columns)

# Join the dataframe
res_df = df[0]
for index in range(1, len(df)):
  res_df.join(df[index], how='outer')

# Or if you only want to merge
pd.concat(df, join='outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would use generator to save memory of your machine time of execution could be longer but your machine will process only one file a a time

```
import os
import pandas as pd 


def census_dataframes():
    for filename in os.listdir(output_path):
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            yield pd.read_csv(os.path.join(output_path, filename))
        else:
            continue
            
            
dataframes = census_dataframes()

#get first dataframe from generator
df1 = next(dataframes)

for frame in dataframes:

    df1 = df1.merge(frame, how = 'left', on = ['Location+Type', 'Year', 'state', 'Census_tract', 'County_name'])
```

If above approach do not bring result then please check the size of your output dataframe.
For effective use you need at least 2x more memory than your dataframe requires.

Further memory savings can be done by optimizing datatypes during reading csv like

```
yield pd.read_csv(os.path.join(output_path, filename), dtype= {‘a’: np.float32, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ....})
```

in case you have text entries that frequently repeats in column ( like 'Man', 'Female', 'Not Disclosed', ... ) you can convert them to categories and save significant amount of memory. However to do this on large population of files requires prior preparation, upfront categories definition.
Please refer to pandas documentation on topic 'Categorical Data'

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code but it still gave me "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." The files make up 5.7 gb of memory and I have 64 gb of ram on this computer (4 16 gb DDR4)

Comment: If your kernel keeps dying then a/ try using pure python outside of notebook. This can provide more stability. b/ while using generator method you can save intermediate results   every N files and restart the process from the moment it has last checkpoint. This is going to take significantly longer.

Comment: Is it possible to parallelize the latter above?

Comment: Yes, it is possibe using standard libraries of python. The bottleneck can be IO processes of the disk.